# made condition on column in view

Tags: sql-server

I have made a view in which i use function to get a column something like that

```
dbo.GetFinalLetter(Id, CASE 
        WHEN Id IN (
                ---------
                )
            THEN 1
        WHEN Id IN (
                --------
                )
            THEN 0
        END) as LetterText
```

so i want to put an other condition that only those results been shown that have text in that column for that purpose i used

```
where LetterText <> null

where LetterText not null
```

but it shows error

Comment: Select clause column aliases are cannot be used in where clauses.  You'll need to either repeat the function in the where clause or encapsulate the select statement in a CTE.  Also, use `IS NOT NULL` to check for NULL values.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to move your function call to an `OUTER/CROSS APPLY` and then use the `APPLY` result to check your value:

```
SELECT <your columns>
FROM <your tables>
    CROSS APPLY 
    (
        SELECT dbo.GetFinalLetter(Id, CASE 
        WHEN Id IN (
                ---------
                )
            THEN 1
        WHEN Id IN (
                --------
                )
            THEN 0
        END) as LetterText
    ) AS x
WHERE x.LetterText IS NOT NULL ;
```

OR you can also use a subquery of the full query:

```
SELECT <your columns>
FROM 
(
    SELECT <your columns>,
        dbo.GetFinalLetter(Id, CASE 
        WHEN Id IN (
                ---------
                )
            THEN 1
        WHEN Id IN (
                --------
                )
            THEN 0
        END) as LetterText
    FROM <your tables>
) AS t
WHERE LetterText IS NOT NULL ;
```

The way to do that may depend on the data volume of the tables.

Hope this helps.